# How to stop htmlentites when use summernote and laravel to send html e-mail?

Tags: angularjs, email, laravel, summernote

I am having an issue with Laravel 5.1 and summernote. I am using summernote to compose an email which I am sending via angular.js to a laravel 5.1 API.

I have debugged as much as I can but I cannot seem to get the email sending in HTML code that renders correctly.

The message source correctly shows that the email is being sent in HTML but somehow the body of the email keeps being converted to htmlentities and the then HTML code is showing in the email body when received.

My mail send command in Laravel is as follows.

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$body = $params['body'];

$to_address = $params['to'];
$subject = $params['subject'];

Mail::send(['html' => 'emails.send_email'], ['body'=>$body], function ($message) use ($to_address, $subject){
        $message->from($to_address);
        $message->subject($subject);
        $message->to($to_address);

});
```

The text body text I have tried in summernote is simply,

```
Test

Test
```

Which is coming through as

```
test<br>test
```

Message source has this in it which is leading me to the htmlentities issue.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<body>
test&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;test&lt;br&gt;
</body>
```

The Angular.js code to gather the summernote details

```
sendEmail($scope.to, $scope.subject, $scope.body).then(function(){
            // Clear out the compose
            $scope.subject = '';
            $scope.body = '';

            $scope.success_message_sent = true;
        });
```

Then the sending function

```
    $scope.sendEmail = function(to, subject, body) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var data = {
        'to': to,
        'subject': subject,
        'body': body
    };

    $http.post('http://'+ remoteServer +'/api/send_email', data)
        .success(function() { deferred.resolve(); })
        .error(function() { deferred.reject("Failed to send message");
    }); 

    return deferred.promise;
```

I am using Mandrill to send the email.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: am not sure if this is laravel issue. Please why are doing this `file_get_contents('php://input')` and not using laravel request methods such as `Input::get('summernote_name')`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have changed to Input::get. When I debug the value in laravel (php) I see the correct format. This along with running Html::decode etc. However I don't discount it being a summernote / angular.js cause. Trying to find out how I can test/debug in angular or summernote to try resolve this.

Comment: Can you trying `dd(Input::get('summernote_name'))` and see what is actually submitted ?

Comment: Hi, I get this, "test<br>test<br>"

Comment: great. this means the issue is not coming from summernote or angularjs. I think the issue is coming from your mail template. remember to use `{!! $body !!}` to output the message in the template

Comment: There is not issue with your angularjs code and summernote. Have you checked your email template like i suggested? Also use `Mail::send('emails.send_email', ...`

Comment: Thank you, completely missed the email template! You rock, sorted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this issue is coming from your template:

In your `emails.send_email.blade.php` use `{!! $body !!}` to prevent htmlentities issue

Comment: Hi, I am using an angular form with the summernote value coming from a ng-modal binding. Then I am sending the email via $http. So not using laravel for the composer. I was hoping to find something like that for Angular ng-modal binding because the symptom seems identical.

Comment: can you add angularjs code for sending mail in your question.

Comment: That's it added to the question. Thanks ;)

Comment: Sorry for mis-reading your previous advice. I was thinking about the compose template not the actual email one! Sorted thanks!